# ADO Batch Update in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado

I am trying to use batch updates in Access VBA. My code works fine when I update after every operation, but fails when I try to operate on multiple rows. The exception I get is

> "Run-time error '-2147217887 (80040e21)': Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done."

My code is

```
rs.Open "dbrammDump", CurrentProject.Connection, _
            adOpenKeyset, adLockBatchOptimistic
rowsDel = 0
Do Until rs.RecordCount < 1
    rs.MoveFirst
    rs.Delete

    rowsDel = rowsDel + 1
Loop
rs.UpdateBatch
```

Any ideas what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you need to explicitly use a client-side cursor. I suspect that you are implicitly using a server-side cursor.

I prefer to set the recordset object's properties individually because I think it is easier to read (and therefore debug) than using the overloaded `Open` method. Also, you can use the `RecordCount` property for your loop e.g.

```
With rs
  .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
  .Source = "dbrammDump"
  .CursorLocation = adUseClient  ' <<< THIS MISSING FROM ORIGINAL CODE
  .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
  .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
  .Open

  Dim counter As Long
  For counter = 0 To .RecordCount - 1
      .Delete
      .MoveNext
  Next

  .UpdateBatch

  rowsDel = counter

End With
```

FWIW I agree with others here that a set-based solution in SQL is preferable to procedural code such as that above.

Comment: You know, I don't think that's going to do a batch update unless you disconnect the recordset first. After `.Open`, you need to do `Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing`, then before the `.UpdateBatch`, do `Set .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection`.

Comment: Hmm... I can't seem to get disconnected recordsets working right so far. So perhaps my comment was premature.

Comment: Aha! I was not using `adLockBatchOptimistic`. `adLockOptimistic` prevents batch updates from working.

Comment: @Emtucifor: batch updates should work regardless of whether connected or disconnected provided your use adLockBatchOptimistic (and that the OLE DB provider and/or source supports it).

Comment: Yeah, it was the lock type I was missing. Sorry about the misinformation. Now that I'm onto the issue about lock type, I see that you don't have to disconnect the recordset to prevent the updates from occurring as you make the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you deleting records in this manner, when you could call `myconnection.Execute "DELETE FROM myTable WHERE....."`?

Also, how have you opened the recordset? Paste the `myrecordset.Open(...)` statement here.
See if this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_open.asp#LockTypeEnum) helps.

Comment: True, that would be better for this case (thanks :-). However, I am also inserting a few thousand rows - and would like to do this batched rather than individually.

Comment: Is the source of your inserts a data set that can be used in a SELECT statement to be appended as a batch? If so, that's your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is the source of your inserts a data set that can be used in a SELECT statement to be appended as a batch? If so, that's your answer.

If you need the number of rows deleted/inserted/updated with ADO code use the following.

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSQL, lngRecordsAffected, adCmdText
```